# "Every proper subset of the indiscrete space is nowhere dense"

Tags: general-topology

> Every proper subset of the indiscrete space is nowhere dense.

This is a claim from Sasho Kalajdzievski's *An illustrated introduction to topology and homotopy* (section 3.4, Example 3, p. 59). I think this is wrong, because $A = \{0\}$ is a proper subset of the indiscrete space $(X, \tau) = (\{0, 1\}, \{\varnothing, \{0,1\}\})$, but $\overline{A} = \{0,1\} \,\therefore\, \mathrm{int}\,(\overline{A}) = \{0,1\}$. Am I right?

Comment: Yes, you’re right. Every non-empty subset of a whose topology is indiscrete is actually dense in the space. **No** non-empty subset is nowhere dense.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The author should have written that every nontrivial proper subset is dense, or something along those lines.  This appears to be an error.

Comment: But, by definition, $A$ is nowhere dense if and only if $\mathrm{int}(\overline{A}) = \varnothing$. What I have to consider is not the closure of the interior, but the interior of the closure.

Comment: You're right, I got that backwards.

Comment: I have considered the topology $\tau = \{\varnothing, \{0, 1\}\}$ on the set $X = \{0, 1\}$. This is the trivial topology.

Comment: I see.  But then shouldn't you write $\tau=\{\emptyset,\{0,1\}\}$?  I'm still thinking about your main question.

Comment: A topological space is an ordered pair. I wrote an equality of ordered pairs:  $(X, \tau) = (\{0, 1\}, \{\varnothing, \{0,1\}\})$. This means that $X = \{0, 1\}$ and $\tau = \{\varnothing, \{0,1\}\}$.

Comment: Ok, I see what you mean.

Comment: I think you're right.

Comment: I think the author wanted to say that every proper subset of the indiscrete space is *not* nowhere dense.